# How to identify the wheel rotating animation on a UIPickerView?

Tags: iphone, uipickerview

I am working with a iPhone app,where i have a scenario in which i have to identify when the wheel rotating animations starts when the user swipes over the component on the UIPIckerView.

Where should i use

[UIPickerView setAnimationWillStartSelector:@selector()];

method to identify the animation started event.

Please any body suggest me a solution to make this happen.

Thank you one and all.

Answer (score 1):

Sankar Chandara Bose. You can identify the UIPickerView wheel rotation by using the UIPickerView delegate/datasource.

```
- (void)pickerView:(UIPickerView *)pickerView didSelectRow:(NSInteger)row inComponent:(NSInteger)component
```

You can get the UIPickerView wheel swipe action and current row from this delegate. I hope you got any ideas from my answer. Thanks.

Comment: Yuva,that method will be called only after the picker view animation is complete.It will not be called when the animation has started.I want some methodology in which the animation began event has to be identified when the component wheel starts rotating. Thank you for your interest for answering to my query.